# Team Lead is not working and delegating all his work to me and getting false credit for it

Tags: leadership, teamwork

We are 3 in number (2 members and 1 Lead).
My team lead is a lazy man. He showcases himself as if he knows all stuff but the fact is he doesn't. He also tactically delegates all the work to me and the other member and avoids his tasks.

He not only delegates his work but being a team he does not do his work -  leading the team. He plainly has no knowledge what is going on in our project and what issues we are facing.

He also created a false impression with our PM who is at onsite. Now I'm endowed with more work (work of the other member and TL) and still I'm accountable for every mistake done by others, while all good credits are being swept by my TL.

What can I do? I cannot ignore work like my other project member does - because somebody has to do the work for the project to go on. But others don't seem to share this responsibility.

Comment: Isn't it a TL's job to delegate? How are you sure he doesn't do anything else?

Comment: I am skeptical of your narrative. If you are that certain of your facts, you are that convinced that you are right and you are that knowledgeable about what's going on, you can complain to the PM and the manager. Winner takes all. Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: @Ajaxkevi I'd say in a three man team as in this situation the TL should be expected to do actual work at least half the time.

Comment: @Fredrik Maybe he is doing actual work, just not work that OP knows about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should we handle 'Jak' who takes credit for others' work and ideas?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11654/how-should-we-handle-jak-who-takes-credit-for-others-work-and-ideas) and of [Handling Credit-takers](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/366/handling-credit-takers)

Comment: I agree that part of the job of the TL is to delegate. Your description sounds like there is more to it, but you should refine it a bit. For example, when he takes credit does he actually claim that he did the work or does he take (part of the) credit by saying he delegated it to the right person? As for your last sentence: it is not your job to hide the shortcoming of your colleagues and supervisors by doing their work as well. Doing so you help hide a problem which is unresponsible.

Comment: Please update your question to present a description of your team-lead's laziness. Does he take long lunches? Does he web surf all the time? Or is it possible that your project has a large administrative workload, and he spends a lot of time talking to the PM and the client?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to continue the work, so the project doesn't fail, what do you really expect the other people to do? Obviously the don't feel sorry for you or feel a need to work harder.

You can always ask them to do more work. Then you can decide to do the work or not. Or you can just stop doing the work and see what happens.

I don't know how long you have been doing this, but you've creating a bad habit for yourself. Either get over it and take pride in the fact that you do all the work for no credit. Otherwise, you're just making yourself miserable. Maybe you can keep this up, but most people can't.

You can always ask for a raise and threaten the TL with leaving. Maybe he won't call your bluff.